# Eclipse file change doesn't reflect in the filesystem

Tags: android, eclipse, file, caching

I got a strange problem about eclipse.  I use TFS explorer in Visual Studio 2012 to save my codes.
From eclipse, I created an android full screen project, check in the code into TFS (from visual studio 2012 because the eclipse tfs plugin cannot connected to my tfs server).
And then I check out and modify the android.manifest to hide the title of the app.  And save the file.

Every thing works perfectly, the title was successfully removed when running the app in the simulator.  Note that all the code change has been saved.

The problem happened when I tried to check in the code change.  TFS told me that no file change was detected.  So I right click the android.manifest and copy the Location from the dialog and open it in Notepad, what surprised me is that TFS is correct, the android.manifest doesn't changed in Notepad.  But in eclipse the content did changed.

Has anybody meet this problem?  Does eclipse cache the file content when I click save?
The problem exists even I close and restart the eclipse.

From eclipse, I can see the latest file content but from any other file viewer that file are still an old one.

**Have checked the location of the file a lot of times, both are the same, but the content still different.  I've also restarted eclipse multiple times.
Everything is correct in eclipse, but outside eclipse, the files seems never changed.**

Comment: I am pretty late but have you tried to go offline and online in eclipse?
- second click project>Team>Offline
- second click project>Team>Online

Answer (score 0):

Once clean your project and check it out. Eclipse rebuilt it again when you clean the project. It'll work.

> Make sure in Project-->Build Automatically should be enabled.

Comment: Build Automatically has already been enabled, clean & build doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to clean the project then check it in eclipse that is it changed or not if not then change it and save 
if u find it did not work then try after restarting the eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

please check file both path with file->properties are same or different.

Comment: Have checked a lot of times, both are the same, but the content still different.  I've also restarted eclipse multiple times.